# Post action is not hit in asp.net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

the Register action is not hit when clicking on the button called 'Save'?:

```
http://localhost/Account/RegisterPlayer
```

controller:

```
   public ActionResult RegisterPlayer()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult RegisterPlayer(Player player)
        {
            //it does not hit this action : (
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

            }

            return View(player);
        }
```

RegisterPlayer.cshtml

```
@model mystuff.Models.Player

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "RegisterPlayer";
}

<h2>RegisterPlayer</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Player</legend>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.id)

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.firstname)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.firstname)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.firstname)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.email)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.email)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.email)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

player class:

```
 public class Player
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string firstname { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }

    }
```

global.asax

```
 public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        }

        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

        }

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean when clicking the button marked 'Saved'?

Comment: @Danm yes you are right sorry for that.

Comment: Can you please provide Player model.

Comment: @AlexeyAnufriyev apologies I changed it.

Comment: Also can you please provide routing config? and also you can try to use form helper overload. If it doesnot help, maybe looking at fiddler logs will help to understand what goes on server.

Comment: @AlexeyAnufriyev I did not change anything to the routing configuration in the global.asax but i posted it . In fiddler nothing shows up , the RegisterPlayer GET request is visible but not the POST request

Comment: you try specifying the action and controller in your submit from. i.e @using (Html.BeginForm("RegisterPlayer", "Accont"))

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending any player objects to your view . You need something like this :

```
 public ActionResult RegisterPlayer()
        {
            Player player=new Player();
            return View(player);
        }
```

I also suggest you use the debugger to see where it crashed . It is obviously a data transfer issue . IF you dont know how to acces the view with a debugger , use F11 to go through it

Comment: this should make no difference

Comment: did you use the debugger to see where it crashes ?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but i think that if the model recieves a null value  of Player within the view it will crash. Telling us what kind of error you get would make our job alot easier

Comment: it does not crash , it does not trigger the RegisterPlayer action

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the `value` of your `input` does not match the action you need.

Try this instead:

```
<input type="submit" value="RegisterPlayer" />
```

Comment: this is just the display text of the submitbutton. The action is: /Account/RegisterPlayer, check the source